# Consume a jText in java with special character

Tags: java

I have a `jText` in java.

I need to band user for using 'SPACE' button wen he is taping and use only numbers !

I'm using this code :

```
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && c != KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
        if (!(c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9' || c == ' ')) {
            if ((c == '.') || (c == ' ')) {

                if (!CNummber.getText().contains("")) {

                } else {
                    evt.consume();
                }

            } else {

                evt.consume();
            }
        }
    }
```

in KeyTyped Event

but for some reason it is not working !

it is tipping A Numbers only but not banning space button

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Fix it using this code :

```
      char c = evt.getKeyChar();

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        evt.consume();
    } else {

        if (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && c != KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
            if (!(c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9' || c == ' ')) {
                if ((c == '.') || (c == ' ')) {

                    if (!CNummber.getText().contains("")) {

                    } else {
                        evt.consume();
                    }

                } else {

                    evt.consume();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```